# Задания к учебнику Шилдта по С++

Tags: c++

Начинаю изучать С++, подобрал себе учебник и купил его. Понравился как пишет автор, это Шилдт С++ - Руководство для начинающих. Но заданий в нем очень мало или совсем нету по глав. Хочу узнать, где брать учебные задания для закрепления знаний на практике. Учебник очень нравится и менять не хочу. Хочу после каждой главы или определенной темы закреплять прочитанное на практике. Посоветуйте пожалуйста источники откуда можно брать задания Варианты придумывать самому не устраивает, так как фантазия у меня в этом направления узкая и браться за какой то проект у меня пока не хватает опыта и знаний. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <Лафоре.Р>      \\ ООП 4-е издание.
#include <Шылдт.Г>       \\ Полный справочник 4-е издание.
#include <Культин.Н>     \\ В задачах и примерах 2-е издание.
#include <Пахомов.Б>     \\ Среда разработки MS Visual C++.
#include <Страуструп.Б>  \\ Любая книга не ошибетесь.

using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам так хочется всяких задачек по главам на С++, то советую приобрести методичку по С++ для вузов. Видел пару таких от разных вузов - в них обычно минимум теории и потом с десяток задачек. Если в вашем вузе нету - сходите в другой, лично у нас в Минске в большинстве вузов(если даже не в каждом) есть своя точка по продаже разнообразных методичек. И стоят такие методички копейки - получается недорого и сердино(на первых парах). А если это для вас не актуально - как вариант поискать в гугле задачники по программированию и выбрать наиболее понравившийся.

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток.

Начинал изучать C++ по Лафоре - ООП в C++. Написана просто и после каждой главы есть ~10 упражнений. Попробуйте упражнения из этой книги.

Answer (score 0):

Мой Вам совет, сначала просто прочитайте весь учебник и постарайтесь выполнить примеры кода оттуда. Если вы только начали изучать C++ Вам этого будет достаточно и не думаю, что Вы сразу всё поймете. Прочитав этот учебник заходите на различные форумы в инете в раздел начинающих и помогайте решать различные простейшие задачи. Потом бы я Вам посоветовал бы почитать Скотта Мейера у него есть 3 книги: Effective C++, More Effective C++ и Eeffective STL. Дак вот прочитайте первую книгу, потом почитайте Страуструпа C++, а потом More Effective C++ и Effective STL. На ближайшие 3-4 месяца Вам этого хватит. Не нужно сильно сейчас упираться в задачи. Достаточно будет тех, которые приведены в книжках. Если уж Вам очень хочется решать, то есть просто замечательная книга "Каррано Ф.М., Причард Дж. Абстракция данных и решение задач на C++. Стены и зеркала". В ней просто МАССА задач на C++, очень и очень много заданий, часть из них разбирается (5%), остальные сами. Так что вперёд.

Comment: Я учу программирование в университете, но качество оставляет желать лучшего. Решил самостоятельно начать с нуля. Спасибо за ваш совет. Я посмотрел книжку которую вы посоветовали, пока что мне это рано. Я еще не имел дело с алгоритмами и структурами данных. Поэтому прошу посоветовать что-нибудь другое как дополнительный задачник к учебнику, потому что в Шилдте ну совсем их нету. Да, я так решил сделать прочитать весь учебник, разобраться с базовым синтаксисом. Но все же зная свой мозг и то как я запоминаю информацию, мне нужно выполнять задания после прочтения каждой главы.

Comment: И что значит "выполнить примеры кода из учебника"?

Comment: Хм... может быть мы смотрим разные учебники Шилдта. Откройте страницу 475, это называется: ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ B. ОТВЕТЫ НА ВОПРОСЫ И РЕШЕНИЯ УПРАЖНЕНИЙ, там даны решения задач, которые даются при прочтении глав. Т.е. читаете главу в конце неё даются задачки. Решаете, а потом проверяете себя. По-моему идеальная схема.

Comment: Я думаю Вам этих задачек хватит надолго. Есть еще книга автор Дейтл "Как программировать на C++", я её читал, но многим она почему-то не нравится. Можете посмотреть, ознакомиться.

Comment: Я учу на практике. Прочитал этот же учебник. Все конечно не понял и не запомнил, но понемногу осиливаю.

Comment: Дейтелы и мне не понравились. Озвучьте пожалуйста учебники в которых есть задания после глав, кроме Дейтелов.

Answer (score 0):

Друг найди в интернете книгу Абрамян М.Э '1000 задач по программированию'.
На фортране решал,все просто по мере решений растет сложность.
Можешь потренироваться на олимпиадника)

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь: [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) довольно много интересных задач. Решайте их, за одно и язык закрепите.